# Sort or order error messages in error_messages (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any (simple) way to get some control of the order in which a model's errors appear in the view? Ordering the rules does not seem to help whatsoever.

Comment: Note: I put my own answer below, which uses the best answer to help it along.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `error_message_on` instead of `error_messages` to get the message for an individual attribute.

```
<div class="errorMessages">
    <% %{name title description}.each do |att| %>
        <%= f.error_message_on att, :css_class => "error" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In 2.3.6 validation messages will show in order you declared them in code

[link](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2301-ensure-ar-validation-errors-to-be-ordered-in-declared-order)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer (for my own notes, basically) using Baldu's answer. This puts the attribute_names in alpha order:

```
<% if @model.errors.length>0 %>
  <div class="errorExplanation">
    <h3>There were problems with the following fields:</h3><ul>
      <% @model.attribute_names.each do |attribute| %>
        <% if !@model.errors[attribute].blank? %>
          <li><%= f.error_message_on attribute, Model.human_attribute_name(attribute)+ "&nbsp;", :style=>"display:inline" %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Of course you can parametrize this further as a partial, for instance. I'll probably do that :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same prob in groovy in rails (grails). changing it in the code does not change anything, the above answer doe not  work for me either. This is how I end up solving my prob. Team created a custom tag for sorting / ordering grails error msgs.

```
def renderOrderedErrors = { attrs, body ->

    def bean = attrs.bean
    def fields = attrs.fields

    fields.each { out << g.renderErrors(bean: bean, field:it) }

}
```

and this is how you use it:

```
<g:if test="${totalRating.hasErrors() || rating.hasErrors()}">
    <div class="errors">
        <g:if test="${totalRating.hasErrors()}"><g:renderOrderedErrors bean="${totalRating}" as="list" fields="${['totalEffectiveDate','awardedDisability']}"/></g:if>
        <g:if test="${rating.hasErrors()}"><g:renderOrderedErrors bean="${rating}" as="list" fields="${['ratingStatus','ratingIssue','disability','effectiveDate','ratingType','socDate','nodDate','ssocDate','form9Date','six46Date','remandDate']}"/></g:if>//this is the way you want to order the fields in the form
    </div>
</g:if>
```